# trying to test input change method but it doesnt seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on an e-commerce website.

At the moment I am trying to get an input number element, which was dynamically created, to prompt an alert message (just as practice) to see if it works. However, nothing seems to happen when I change the input number element. I am not sure what the problem is exactly. Is anyone able to assist? The function which I have put together to add items from an object works perfectly fine, its just the changing of the qty that is not really doing anything.

Thanks in advance for all the helpful responses.

```js
$(".shopnow").click(function() {
  basketCounter++;
  if (basketCounter > 0) {
    $("#items-count").html(basketCounter);
  }
  var currentProduct = this.id;
  if (payForProducts.includes(currentProduct)) {
    document.getElementById(currentProduct + "Input").value++;
  } else {
    payForProducts.push(currentProduct);
    var ulEl = document.createElement("ul");
    var firstLi = document.createElement("li");
    basketContent.insertBefore(ulEl, checkout);
    firstLi.innerText = topProtein[currentProduct].name;
    ulEl.appendChild(firstLi);
    var secondLi = document.createElement("li");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("class", "qtyproduct");
    input.setAttribute("id", currentProduct + "Input");
    input.setAttribute("name", "nameQty")
    input.setAttribute("type", "number");
    input.setAttribute("min", "0");
    input.setAttribute("value", "1");
    secondLi.appendChild(input);
    ulEl.appendChild(secondLi);
    var thirdLi = document.createElement("li");
    thirdLi.innerText = topProtein[currentProduct].price;
    ulEl.appendChild(thirdLi);
  }

})

$("input[name='nameQty']").change(function() {
  alert("testing here!");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basket-content">
  <h1>YOUR SHOPPING BASKET</h1>
  <ul id="basket-headings">
    <li>PRODUCT</li>
    <li>QTY</li>
    <li>PRICE</li>
  </ul>
  <button id="checkoutcomplete">COMPLETE ORDER</button>
  <span class="close-window">CLOSE WINDOW</span>
</div>

<section id="protein-products">

<h1>TOP SELLING PROTEIN RANGE</h1>

<div class="scroll-div">

<span id="left-scroll-protein" class="scrolling-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>

<span id="right-scroll-protein" class="scrolling-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>

</div>

<div id="protscrollproducts">

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein1.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">100% Whey Protein Professional</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound26.39</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product1" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein2.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">MUSCLE MILK (Vanilla) 1120g</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound31.20</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product2" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein3.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Organic Protein Plant-Based Protein Powder</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound13.78</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product3" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein4.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Combat 100% Ultra Premium Whey</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound12.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product4" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein5.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Builder's Protein Bars Box Chocolate - 12 Bars</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound15.39</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product5" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein6.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Ultimate Nutrition: CarneBOLIC protein</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound42.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product6" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein7.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Pure Protein: 100% Whey (vanilla)</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound18.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product7" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein8.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">BodyLab: Fat Burning Protein (Vanilla)</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound16.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product8" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein9.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Plant Based: Tone It Up Protein</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound12.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product9" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein10.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Olly: Nourishing Smoothie Protein</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound17.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product10" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein11.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Premier Protein x 4 (Chocolate)</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound11.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product11" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein12.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Orgain: Organic Slim Protein</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound16.49</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product12" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein13.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Only Protein: Whey Vanilla</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound15.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product13" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein14.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Muscle Milk: Strawberry Whey</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound21.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product14" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein15.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">Kodiak Cakes: Protein Flapjack On The Go x 12</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound19.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product15" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>

<div class="protein-product">

<img src="images/index/protein16.jpg">

<img src="images/5star.jpg">

<span class="heading">EAS: 100% Whey Protein 907g Chocolate</span>

<span class="product-price">&pound12.99</span>

<button class="more-info">MORE INFO</button>
<button id="product16" class="shopnow">ADD TO BASKET</button>


</div>


</div>

</section>
```

Comment: Neither the `.shopnow` nor the `input name="nameQty"` elements are in the HTML you posted...

Comment: I suggest you to isolate the snippet concerned and post a JSFiddle so we can clearly understand what you are asking.

Comment: by the way where is the id `items-count` that contains the counter of articles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, might as well make things readable:

```
$(`<ul>
    <li>${topProtein[currentProduct].name}</li>
    <li>
      <input class="qtyproduct" id="${currentProduct}Input" name="nameQty" type="number" min="0" value="1">
    </li>
    <li>${topProtein[currentProduct].price}<li>
  </ul>`).insertBefore(basketContent);
```

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

As for the nothing happening, event handlers can only be applied to elements that already exist in the DOM. If you're dynamically adding things, you'll either have to re-apply the handler after insertion, or attach the handler to a non dynamically added parent and than use a selector.

```
$(permanent parent element).on('change', 'input[name="nameQty"]', function() {
  alert("testing here!");
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you so much for your great solution my friend! This is working great.

Answer (score 1):

There is a handful of errors remarked in your code:

- `ulEl` is not appended to the body element.
- Few variables undeclared
- Finally `$("input[name='nameQty']").change` could preferably be customized for each new input added to the body of html, in your code the query is triggered before any new elements that possibly would be created, so they won't be assigned to an event-listener.

[here is the summary of everything](https://plnkr.co/edit/mkLZb7f29pikBTLq3wHg?p=preview)

Comment: For the third bullet point, this is where event delegation would be much more useful instead of dynamically adding event handlers

Comment: @AnilRedshift Well, Yes, calling a `foreach` iterator of all inputs after each element insertion is sort of expensive, I was just trying to add the fewest possible changes from the op's mysterious code.

Comment: @Abra001 Hello, thanks for the response. This is my first major project and I am pushing myself to learn more. Thanks for highlighting the errors. I always try and learn from mistakes I make. Responding to your bullet points....as far as I can see I believe I did append the ulEl element "basketContent.insertBefore(ulEl, checkout);" or is this done incorrectly? Please can you let me know which variables are undeclared specifically. Thanks for the third bullet point, I will certainly look to implement that into my code.

Comment: Yes it's done incorrectly, i don't receive enough data from your side to correct it thus i append the elment in a visible way.